# Teleprompter software

Tags: gratis, video-recording

I'm trying to record a few videos with children and neither me nor them can remember the whole text. Reading the text from a sheet of paper works, but does not look good. It would be much better to have some teleprompter software which can be placed near the camera, so the participants seem to look into the camera.

Requirements:

- Do the basic teleprompter task: show text in a large font on a fullscreen display.
- Distinguish different people by a different color, either text color, border color or background color
- works with a 1280x1024 screen (because I happen to have one)
- adjustable font size, so I can use it from different distances
- is gratis
- supports stepping forward by pressing a button

I'm open for solutions on different platforms (Linux, Windows). I'd prefer a solution with Raspberry Pi (because I happen to have one) and a button that is operated by foot. The Raspberry could support that via GPIO, while all other solutions would probably require a keyboard (and then I need to hide the keyboard).

Non-requirements:

- text flipping. I will not use a mirror at the moment.

Comment: Teleprompter needs to be in front of camera, not to one side, unless the talent is a long way from camera [5m or more]. It looks extraordinarily awkward if they appear to be looking just off camera. You need specific hardware for close-up teleprompt, not just software… hence the reflective plain glass & reverse image. Your get-out is if you can manage to stage what feels like an over-shoulder shot, so sight-line is off-cam. Next… you have to teach the kids to take in the entire screen without moving their eyes or head, or again, it looks very awkward. Wish you luck ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin: thanks for the insights. The camera is ~2.5m away at the moment. Looking 20cm off the camera is hopefully much better than looking down onto the table. But yeah, we'll see how awkward it still looks and maybe find a sponsor for hardware, if needed. I hope that my graphic design gut feeling tells me if something is still wrong.

Comment: You might be OK at 2.5m For some reason, my head said 10ft to me, but I thought metric would be a better way to write it, then my maths died & I put 5m, I've no idea why ;)) I did some stuff recently where I was reading from paper prompt. I eventually had to shoot most of it so it looked like I was performing to well off-cam before it stopped looking really uncomfortable. I ended up shooting it from about 8 angles & cutting between to get the best bits; to cam only for the bits I remembered well enough to do straight down the bottle. Wish you all the best.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look at them, these all look suitable:

- https://promptr.tv/ ([source](https://github.com/manifestinteractive/teleprompter))
- https://imaginarysense.github.io/Imaginary-Teleprompter/ - ([source](https://github.com/ImaginarySense/Imaginary-Teleprompter))
- https://kevinhwang.github.io/teleprompter/ ([source](https://github.com/kevinhwang/teleprompter))
- https://qprompt.app/ ([source](https://github.com/Cuperino/QPrompt))
- https://www.prompter.me/ ([source](https://github.com/zilahir/teleprompter))

Comment: This site is about recommendations. I don't like "let me google that for you" answers. From a recommendation, I expect at least some personal experience, i.e. you have used it yourself and know the pros and cons.

Comment: Another thing to consider: given I try all the 5 listed programs and I like 2 of them but I hate 3 of them. Should I then give you an upvote, or a downvote? Should I accept the answer? How should a future reader know which one I picked as my solution?

Comment: Excellent points - I will keep those in mind. Thanks!